# Unable to capture value of id($('.input_fields_wrap').append(h1 tag)). And store value in var data

Tags: jquery

I am trying Capture value of id in $('.input_fields_wrap').append(h1 tag) .And store this value in var data. I am able capture data in whole div tag , but I need only value of Id. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $('.input_fields_wrap')
        .append('{% for s in speaker %}<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center"><img id="button"src="{{s.ProfileImg.url}}"alt=""><h1 class="id"> {{s.id}} </h1><h1 name="name" class="name"> {{s.Name}} </h1> <h4>{{s.Technical_Area}} | {{s.Brief_Bio}} </h4><p>{{s.Email}} | {{s.Phone}} | {{s.Social_Media}}</p><button type="button" class="remove_field">Remove</button> <button type="button" class="edit_field">Edit</button></div>{% endfor%}');
    });

    $('.input_fields_wrap').on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).parent().detach();
         var data = $(this).parent('div').text();

         console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at [`find(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/find/#find-selector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that while detaching the element. Detach returns the detached element so you can query the detached element for `h1.id` and get its text:

```
var data = $(this).parent().detach().find('h1.id').text();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes yes, this solution solved my problem. Thanks for your help muecas